# Bootstrap star-rating inside popover CSS issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rating-system, bootstrap-popover

I"m having a css problem with star-rating inside a popover, the css seems to be ignored.
I'm initiliasing my popover with js like this :

```
$(function () {
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    html: true,
    content: $('#popoverContent').html()
});
});
```

popoverContent :

```
<div id="popoverContent" class="hide">
  <h4><span class="label label-default">Screen</span><input type="number" class="rating" min=0 max=5 step=0.5 data-show-caption="false" data-size="xs"></h4>
</div>
```

However, i think that if i put the code directly in data-content attribute, it may work :

```
<button id="popoverButton" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="<h4><span class="label label-default">Screen</span><input type="number" class="rating" min=0 max=5 step=0.5 data-show-caption="false" data-size="xs"></h4>">
  Rate <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

> edit : I just tried that, and it didn't work either :/

Is there any way to make CSS work ?

Thank's in advance.

Here's a fiddle sample to see what i'm talking about :

https://jsfiddle.net/66xL9sLr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are linking directly to the css resource on github. This does not work with services like fiddle (which specifically warns you about this when you add it).

In the console you should see an error similar to this:

> The stylesheet
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating/master/css/star-rating.min.css
>   was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/plain", is not "text/css".

If you add the CSS manually into the fiddle's CSS field or host the file elsewhere, it works just fine.

That being said, it seems that there the plugin still has an issue with its javascript and the layout bootstrap creates for popovers.

This second issue is caused because the star rating is initialized using the layout of your hidden `#popoverContent` element. The plug in uses the dimensions, etc of that element, not the new one in your popover.

To fix this I did the following:

1. Remove the `.rating` class from your input. This prevents the plugin
   from initializing it before it gets added to the popover.
2. Bind to the popover's `inserted.bs.popover` and initialize the rating there. Now, the rating plugin will run its code using the layout of the element that was just inserted into the popover.

The relevant code can be seen here:

```
...

<div id="popoverContent" class="hide">
  <h4><span class="label label-default">Screen (Quality)</span><input class="ratingInput" type="number" min=0 max=5 step=0.5 data-show-caption="false" data-size="xs"></h4>
</div>

...

$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        html: true,
        content: function() {
          return $('#popoverContent').html();
        }
    });

  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('inserted.bs.popover', function () {
    $( 'body .popover .ratingInput' ).rating('create');
  });
});
```

Updated fiddle available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tg75x6r9/).

Comment: @codeless Found a solution for the second issue. Answer updated.

Comment: Still not working, it took me back to first problem, as if no css is detected.
I think i should not remove rating class !

Comment: @codeless How does your code differ from the linked pen? It works there.

Comment: Really ? it works for you ? it doesn't for me even in the linked pen !

Comment: It worked for me in Firefox. I checked in Chrome and got the same issue with the star rating js file. I went ahead and added it in manually (as with the CSS file). Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/by2vjyxe/1/

Comment: Now it works on the jsFiddle but not in my local files because my button is inside : <section><table><tr><td><button> ...
I updated your jsfiddle to make it look like my real code and it didn't work :
https://jsfiddle.net/by2vjyxe/2/

Comment: @codeless I've modified the code to be more robust. It should work in a much more general case now.

Comment: Much Appreciated, now it works Great ! You Rock dude :)

Answer (score -1):

Strange, did you try with inline styling ?

Comment: Yeah, i tried that, as well as other css properties : 
'position:relative,
float:right'
not sure if was meant to solve the problem, but just to let you know